# External Style Sheet Extension

Tags: css, html

I'm currently learning about html and css. I've learnt about this code,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/styles.css">
```

It was said that external stylesheets can be loaded with 3 ways, and that's one of the ways.

So my question is, does that mean I have to upload my stylesheet to a specific website so I can access the stylesheet my html document?

ps. sorry for bad english

edit: the link comes from w3schools, i'm learning the basics from there. if i shouldn't have done that please tell me so i can remove it.

Comment: You can put a relative path there, it doesn't have to be an absolute URL. But you will need to upload the entire website **somewhere** if you want it to be public, so, the real answer is "no, you don't have to upload it to a DIFFERENT place than the rest of your website"

Comment: thanks for your reply. i get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/styles.css">
```

Will download the styles.css file from www.w3schools.com/html/. In that case, you only have to upload your html file. The downside is that if the w3schools.com admin deletes the file *you don't have control over his decision* , your page will not find it anymore.

The best thing to do is to put a local `my_styles.css` file in the same folder as your html file and then

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my_styles.css">
```

This means you will have to upload your html file and `my_styles.css`. In this case the style will be always available for the webbrowsers to download.

Comment: I would not recommend putting all of your CSS files in the same folder as your HTML files. The convention is to put them in a `css` folder for organization.

Comment: Thats true RyanDay, when the number of files increases, it is better to organize in folders.

Answer (score 0):

> does that mean I have to upload my stylesheet to a specific website so I can access the stylesheet

No. The stylesheet needs a URL so the browser can access it. It doesn't have to be a URL hosted by a particular website.

It doesn't matter where that URL resolves to (unless it is one that isn't accessible to the browser — e.g. if the URL is on a private LAN and the browser isn't on that LAN).

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't have to be uploaded anywhere. The `href` attribute simply expresses where the file is. The value of the `href` can be **relative** or **absolute**.

### Relative

Relative paths are relative to the folder your HTML file is in. So imagine you have an HTML page `webpage.html` and a CSS file `styles.css` in the following folder structure:

```
My Website
|-- css
|   `-- style.css
|-- images
`-- webpage.html
```

Your link element could use a relative path like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

`../` to go up a folder, then `css/` to go into the css foler.

### Absolute

An absolute path points to the same place no matter where you're pointing from. In the folder structure above, if `My Website` was the root directory of our website, we could use absolute paths a couple different ways:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
```

`/` to start at the root directory, then `css/` to go into the css folder

#### OR

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/css/styles.css">
```

This would directly load your CSS from the URL like the w3schools example.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my_style.css" />
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_type.asp

```
<style type="text/css">
...
</style>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/CSS/@import

```
@import 'custom.css';
```